# javascript variable global and local scope confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../URL'
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {               
    items = data;
})

if(items > 0){
// do something
}
```

`items` is not defined in my case. I wonder I assigned data into items which with no var, so it's a global variable. I also tried declare `items = ""` in global scope, the success scope doesn't overwrite and assign data into it.

Comment: Your problem is not local/global, it is treating an asynchronous call as a synchronous call. The `items > 0` check runs before `items=data` is even run.

Comment: Please show us the actual code you used because the syntax errors in your question make it impossible to know what you are _really_ doing.  That said, I'll be willing to wager that you tried to assign `items` in a callback, so your `if (items > 0)` happened before the assignment....

Comment: $http returns a promise. You should use the then() function to execute code when the promise resolves successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the manipulation of data obtained after the success callback outside the it, which should not be done.

the below part

```
if(items > 0){
// do something
}
```

where you manipulate the data obtained after the callback should be inside the success callback itself. Making the variable global is not the way to achieve it as the code is not executed synchronous way.

so the if condition

```
if(items > 0){
// do something
}
```

will be getting executed even before the success callback get triggered. And hence the `items` variable will not be set by that time.

your code should be like

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {               
    items = data;
    //do your manipulation here
})
```